# Выборка из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Есть следующий массив [id] => [parent_id]

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 5
    [10] => 5
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 4
    [14] => 9
    [15] => 9
    [16] => 9
    [17] => 4
    [18] => 4
    [19] => 2
    [20] => 2
    [21] => 1
    [22] => 1
    [23] => 5
    [24] => 5
    [25] => 14
    [26] => 14
    [27] => 19
    [28] => 19
    [29] => 27
    [30] => 28
)
```

Помогите с написанием функции, которая по заданному ключу id будет заносить в новый массив ключи id потомков. Т.е. если, к примеру, задать начальный ключ 5, то должен вернуться массив со следующими числами: 5,9,10,23,24,14,15,16,25,26 
Порядок чисел не важен

Comment: Если честно, я не понял по примеру вашему "5,9,10,23,24,14,15,16,25,26"

Comment: берем начальный ключ 5. Ищем элемент с id = 5. Заносим в массив. Далее ищем все элементы с parent_id = 5. Заносим их в массив. Затем берем id этих элементов и ищем элементы с таким parent_id и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перелопатьте список, построив полноценное дерево (если это дерево, конечно). Берете очередную вершину из списка, втыкаете на положенное место, повторяете.

Когда у Вас будет (пишу с нотацией `[…]` ≡ `Array(…)`)

```
[1 => [5  => [9  => [14 => …, 15 => [], 16 => []],
              10 => …,
              23 => …,
              24 => …],
       7  => …,
       21 => …,
       22 => …],
 2 => …,
 3 => …,
 4 => …]
```

То работа с деревом будет тривиальна. Полученное дерево, разумеется, стоит сохранить и использовать вместо списка везде, где потребуется.

Если не хочется строить дерево, или в графе возможны циклы, то просто ищите очередных потомков и добавляйте. Псевдокод:

```
function children(graph, node) {       // graph — ваш массив, node — начальный ключ
    result = {node};                   // Множество-результат
    pending = {node};                  // Множество узлов, ожидающих обработки
    while (count(pending) > 0) {       // Пока есть непросмотренные узны
        node = pending.pop();          // Вытаскиваем из мн-ва любой узел
        if (!result.contains(node)) {  // Защита от циклов, если уже видели такой
            children = array_keys(graph, node, true); // Находим непосредств. детей
            pending += children;       // Запоминаем для обработки
            result += children;        // И добавляем к результату
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Надеюсь, идея понятна, и сделать дальше будет несложно.

Я использовал псевдо-синтаксис `{}` для обозначения множества. В PHP нет типа «множество», но его можно сэмулировать ассоциативным массивом, в котором игнорируются значения ключей.